# How to do pairwise comparisons for Kruskal Wallis test?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test

If the null hypothesis in the Kruskal Wallis test is rejected, How can we perform pairwise comparisons? Can we apply Dunnett's Test for that?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a post-hoc test that is designed for the Kruskal-Wallis test.  A common one is the Dunn (1964) test.  This is a rank-based test, that is somewhat like performing pairwise Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney tests, but uses the ranks from the whole Kruskal-Wallis test, not just the individual pairs.

Comment: I would use a generalization of the KW test: the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model, and do pairwise contrasts using that model.  See https://fharrell.com/post/rpo